# Can I pass a path parameter to Cmd/Powershell session/bookmark in MobaXterm?

Tags: powershell, cmd, mobaxterm

According to [this](https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-command-lines/) page, users can pass path parameters to MobaXterm terminals. The syntax to do this is

```
MobaXterm.exe -openfolder "<Folder_name>"
```

It worked when using with its own local terminal, but not with option "`-bookmark Powershell`" or "`-bookmark Cmd`". I've tested the function with the registry key "`\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenWithMobaXterm\command`". Its original value is "`"D:\path to mobaxterm\MobaXterm.exe" -openfolder "%v"`" and it works fine. When I change it to "`"D:\path to mobaxterm\MobaXterm.exe"  -bookmark "CMD" -openfolder "%v"`", it opens CMD with its path set to the home folder of mobaxterm.